# ¿Por qué "tar --exclude=´${dir_ignorar}´" no se ejecuta correctamente?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

estoy creando un simple script (**backup_home.sh**) para hacer backups de un usuario, tengo lo siguiente:

```
#Configuracion del backup home
#--------------------------------
current_date=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
user='juanito'
dir_backup="/home/.backups/home_${user}"
dir_guardar="/home/${user}"
dir_ignorar="/home/${user}/Documentos/.backups"
nombre_fichero_backup="backup_home_${user}_${current_date}.tar.gz"
####################################################################

echo "------------------------------";
echo "Comienzo del backup de '${dir_guardar}'($(date +%d-%m-%Y))";
echo "------------------------------";

echo "fecha = ${current_date}"
echo "directorio backup = ${dir_backup}"
echo "directorio a guardar = ${dir_guardar}"
echo "directorio a ignorar = ${dir_ignorar}"
echo "nombre fichero backup = ${nombre_fichero_backup}"


tar --exclude=´${dir_ignorar}´ -zcvpf ${dir_guardar} ${dir_backup}



echo "------------------------------";
echo "Fin del backup de '${dir_guardar}'";
echo "------------------------------";
```

cuando lo ejecuto (**sh backup_home.sh**) me arroja el siguiente error:

```
tar (child): /home/juanito: No se puede efectuar open: Es un directorio
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/home/.backups/home_juanito/
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las tildes invertidas `` ejecutan el comando entre ellas y son remplazadas por
el resultado del comando. No las necesitas en `--exclude`, podes usar "".

Con las opciones que le pasaste a `tar`, espera el *archivo* de salida y el
directorio a comprimir, pero le estas pasando el directorio a comprimir y el
directorio de salida.

El comando corregido:

```
tar --exclude="${dir_ignorar}" -zcvpf "${dir_backup}/${nombre_fichero_backup}" "${dir_guardar}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Por si sirve de ayuda, en su día me hice un script para hacer backups de mis ficheros. No contesta a la pregunta, pero supongo que puede ser de utilidad al sitio:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Script interactivo para copia de seguridad de directorios 
clear
echo " "
echo "###################################################"
echo "#                                                 #"
echo "# Este script le hará una copia de seguridad      #"
echo "# de un directorio de su elección                 #"
echo "#                                                 #"
echo "###################################################"
echo " "
cd ~ # Ingresamos en el directorio /home del usuario
# Solicitamos una ruta de directorio
echo "Por favor, introduzca la ruta del directorio del que desea hacer backup:"
echo "# Intruduzca el directorio por su ruta completa #"                                    
read Dir
# y nos aseguramos de que dicho directorio existe
if [ ! -d  $Dir ] ; then            
        echo -e "$Dir no es un directorio válido \r"
        echo -e "Saliendo... \a Beeep!" 
# La opción \a de echo requiere el módulo de campana del sistema activo 
# Pruebe a chequearlo escribiendo como root 'lsmod | grep pcspkr'
# ('modinfo pcspkr' le suministrará una información más detallada)
        exit 1
fi
# Asegurémonos, en todo caso, de que se ha introducido al menos un caracter en la solicitud de directorio
if [ -z $Dir ] ; then
        echo -e "$Dir no es un directorio válido \r"
        echo -e "Saliendo... \a Beeep!" 
        exit 1
fi
# Evitemos que se puedan volcar en backup directorios comprometedores
# Nos ceñiremos sólo a hacer backup de directorios de los usuarios
Owner=`ls -al $Dir | head --lines=4 | tail --lines=1 | awk {'print $3'}`
if [ $USER != $Owner ] ; then
        echo "Sólo puede hacer copia de sus propios directorios"
        echo -e "Saliendo... \a Beeep!" 
        exit 1

fi
# Comprobemos que existe un lugar donde volcar la copia; ingresamos en él
# (Usaremos el comando test para variar)
if test -d /tmp/backups ; then
    cd /tmp/backups
else
    mkdir /tmp/backups && cd /tmp/backups
fi
# Declaramos una variable útil para nombrar el backup
Fecha=`date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M`
# Y procedemos a realizar el backup, de acuerdo a la interacción del usuario
for Copia in `ls`
do
    echo "Existe un archivo llamado $Copia"
    echo "¿Desea sobreescribirlo (s/n)?"
    read Accion
    case $Accion in
        s|S)
            tar cvfz $Copia.tgz $Dir
            mv $Copia.tgz backup.$Fecha.tgz
            echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
            echo "Se ha sobreescrito el backup"
            echo "Recuerde que el backup se encuentra en /tmp/backups"
            exit 0 ;;
        n|N)
            tar cvfzk backup.tgz $Dir
            mv backup.tgz backup.$Fecha.tgz
            echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
            echo "Se ha respetado el backup anterior y se ha generado uno nuevo"
            echo "Recuerde que el backup se encuentra en /tmp/backups"
            exit 0 ;;
        *)
            echo "No es una respuesta válida"
            echo "No se hace nada"
            echo -e "Saliendo... \a Beeep!" 
            exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
# En caso de ser la primera vez que se ejecute el script,
# o si hemos eliminado los backups de /tmp/backups
# el bucle anterior no haría nada, dado que /tmp/backups estaría vacio:
Previo=`ls | grep tgz`
if [ -f $Previo ] ; then 
    tar cvfz $Copia.tgz $Dir
    mv $Copia.tgz backup.$Fecha.tgz
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Se ha creado el backup"
    echo "Recuerde que el backup se encuentra en /tmp/backups"
else
    exit 0
fi
exit 0
```

Entiendo que está sobradamente comentado, por lo que veo innecesario explicar el código.
Suerte.

Edito:
De acuerdo a la propuesta de @Cuauhtli, propongo una variante más "cool", para evitar tanto `echo`. Sólo para las primeras líneas, al fin y al cabo sigo sin responder a la pregunta.Tampoco borro arriba para apreciar diferencias. Gracias, @Cuauhtli, la verdad es que el código queda mucho más elegante con un pequeño here-cocument:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Script interactivo para copia de seguridad de directorios 
clear
cat <<DELIMITADOR 

###################################################
#                                                 #
# Este script le hará una copia de seguridad      #
# de un directorio de su elección                 #
#                                                 #
###################################################

DELIMITADOR
```

Comment: ¡Demasiados `echo` para mis ojos! Estaría cool que mejor utilizaras algo como un *here-document*.

Comment: Cuauhtli, no te falta razón. En mi defensa te diré que cuando escribí eso, no sabía ni lo que era un     printf , cuando menos un here-document. De hecho, ni sé el tiempo que me llevó pulir el script. Te tomo la palabra, y lo modificaré cuando saque un rato. Gracias por el apunte.

Comment: No entendí exactamente la edición. A que os referís con un here-document

Comment: Un here-document viene a ser una sección de código que será tratada por el intéprete como si fuese un fichero independiente, de tal manera que permite introducir texto de manera literal (no se interpretarán los símbolos especiales, saltos de línea, sangrados...) en el script, para que sea, en este caso en concreto, mostrado en la salida standart. Evitamos así, como propuso @Cuauhtli, el uso repetido de echo.